# What are the optimizations facilitated by -ffinite-math-only?

Tags: optimization, gcc, compiler-construction, floating-point

All the info I can find in documentation and the web for -ffinite-math-only is "Allow optimizations for floating-point arithmetic that assume that arguments and results are not NaNs or +-Infs." This does not seem forthcoming to me. Does anyone know exactly *what* those optimizations are?
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps `x == x` will optimized to true.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lots of little things can be optimized under that assumption, like:

- `x == x` --> `1`
- `x * 1` --> `x`
- `x >= y` --> `!(x < y)` and similar.
- `x/x` --> `1` if the compiler can prove `x != 0`.
- it may allow a compiler to use hardware max/min instructions for expressions like `x > y ? x : y`.
- ... lots more

You often see this assumption together with assumptions like "sign of zero doesn't matter", which then allows things like:

- `x - x` --> `0`
- `0 / x` --> `0`
- `x * 0` --> `0`